# How to save data in a kendo grid without using the KendoGrid toolbar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The grid I have set up for testing is this

```
function TestCatalogDefaultsGrid() {
    $("#testCatalogDefaultGrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [{
            field: "Catalog",
            template: '<select class="form-control" ><option>Select A</option><option>Select B</option></select>',
            title: "Catalog"
        },
        {
            field: "Multiplier",
            title: "Multiplier"
        },
        {
            field: "Markup",
            title: "Markup"
        },
        {
            field: "AccountNumber",
            title: "Account Number"
        },
        {
            field: "UOM",
            title: "UOM"
        }],
        editable: true,
        batch: true,
        dataSource: {
            data: [{
                Catalog: "",
            },
            {
                Catalog: "",
            }
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

I also have a button for saving that when clicked I would like to save the values in the all the columns to a database, I have a JavaScript object that will hold the data until I the Save button is clicked, the JavaScript object is as follows:

```
    function DataHold() {
    var dataToDatabase = {
    Catalog: "Catalog",
    Multiplier: "Multiplier",
    Markup: "Markup",
    AccountNumber: "AccountNumber",
    UOM: "UOM"
    }
    return dataToDatabase;
}
```

and this is my clickevent where I want to get the data and where I will post my data

```
    $("#btnTestSaveCatalogDefaults").click(function () {
        var myData = DataHold();
    });
```

I have looked around on the Kendo forums and haven't found anything close to what I am doing the way I am doing it, and if this is a duplicate question then would someone please direct me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

In your view define:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourMethod", "Your controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="yourData" name="requests" /> 
    @Html.Button("Post data", new { id = "post-data" })
}
```

In your grid initialization:

```
dataSource: {
                    data: ...,
                    schema:....,                    
                    change: function () { $("#yourData").val(kendo.stringify(this.data().toJSON())); }
                },
```

In your controller:

```
 public ActionResult SubmitPriceChangeTask(string data)
 {
  .........parse your data
 }
```

Comment: I just tried that to no avail. I am going to have a hidden field with the catalogID in it then I want to save the changes in every row that contains a catalog.